# Convert output of tree command to json format

Tags: text-processing, tree, json

Is there a convenient way to convert the output of the *nix command `tree` to JSON format? My goal is to convert something like:

```
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- dirA
|   |   |-- dirAA
|   |   `-- dirBB
|   `-- dirB
`-- dir2
    |-- dirA
    `-- dirB
```

into:

```
{"dir1" : [{"dirA":["dirAA", "dirAB"]}, "dirB"], "dir2": ["dirA", "dirB"]}
```

Comment: @BausTheBig - I don't think you've thought this through all the way. The `tree` command isn't the right tool. I might be inclined to do `ls -R` or a `find` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Attempt 1

A solution using just perl, returning a simple hash of hashes structure. Before the
OP clarified data format of JSON.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;
use JSON;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirs={};
my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty;

find({wanted => \&process_dir, no_chdir => 1 }, ".");
print $encoder->encode($dirs);

sub process_dir {
    return if !-d $File::Find::name;
    my $ref=\%$dirs;
    for(split(/\//, $File::Find::name)) {
        $ref->{$_} = {} if(!exists $ref->{$_});
        $ref = $ref->{$_};
    }
}
```

`File::Find` module works in a similar way to the unix `find` command. The `JSON` module takes perl variables and converts them into JSON.

```
find({wanted => \&process_dir, no_chdir => 1 }, ".");
```

Will iterate down the file structure from the present working directory calling the subroutine `process_dir` for each file/directory under ".", and the `no_chdir` tell perl not to issue a `chdir()` for each directory it finds.

`process_dir` returns if the present examined file is not a directory:

```
return if !-d $File::Find::name;
```

We then grab a reference of the existing hash `%$dirs` into `$ref`, split the file path around `/` and loop with `for` adding a new hash key for each path.

Making a directory structure like slm did:

```
mkdir -p dir{1..5}/dir{A,B}/subdir{1..3}
```

The output is:

```
{
   "." : {
      "dir3" : {
         "dirA" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         },
         "dirB" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         }
      },
      "dir2" : {
         "dirA" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         },
         "dirB" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         }
      },
      "dir5" : {
         "dirA" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         },
         "dirB" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         }
      },
      "dir1" : {
         "dirA" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         },
         "dirB" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         }
      },
      "dir4" : {
         "dirA" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         },
         "dirB" : {
            "subdir2" : {},
            "subdir3" : {},
            "subdir1" : {}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

#### Attempt 2

Okay now with different data structure...

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;

my $encoder = JSON->new->ascii->pretty;   # ascii character set, pretty format
my $dirs;                                 # used to build the data structure

my $path=$ARGV[0] || '.';                 # use the command line arg or working dir

# Open the directory, read in the file list, grep out directories and skip '.' and '..'
# and assign to @dirs
opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
my @dirs = grep { ! /^[.]{1,2}/ && -d "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

# recurse the top level sub directories with the parse_dir subroutine, returning
# a hash reference.
%$dirs = map { $_ => parse_dir("$path/$_") } @dirs;

# print out the JSON encoding of this data structure
print $encoder->encode($dirs);

sub parse_dir {
    my $path = shift;    # the dir we're working on

    # get all sub directories (similar to above opendir/readdir calls)
    opendir(my $dh, $path) or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
    my @dirs = grep { ! /^[.]{1,2}/ && -d "$path/$_" } readdir($dh);
    closedir($dh);

    return undef if !scalar @dirs; # nothing to do here, directory empty

    my $vals = [];                            # set our result to an empty array
    foreach my $dir (@dirs) {                 # loop the sub directories         
        my $res = parse_dir("$path/$dir");    # recurse down each path and get results

        # does the returned value have a result, and is that result an array of at 
        # least one element, then add these results to our $vals anonymous array 
        # wrapped in a anonymous hash
        # ELSE
        # push just the name of that directory our $vals anonymous array
        push(@$vals, (defined $res and scalar @$res) ? { $dir => $res } : $dir);
    }

    return $vals;  # return the recursed result
}
```

And then running the script on the proposed directory structure...

```
./tree2json2.pl .
{
   "dir2" : [
      "dirB",
      "dirA"
   ],
   "dir1" : [
      "dirB",
      {
         "dirA" : [
            "dirBB",
            "dirAA"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I found this pretty damn tricky to get right (especially given the "hash if sub directories, array if not, OH UNLESS top level, then just hashes anyway" logic). So
I'd be surprised if this was something you could do with `sed` / `awk` ... but then
Stephane hasn't looked at this yet I bet :)

Answer (score 26):

Version 1.7 includes support for JSON:
http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/changes.html

Per the `man` page (under `XML/JSON/HTML OPTIONS`):

```
-J     Turn on JSON output. Outputs the directory tree as an JSON formatted array.
```

e.g.

```
$ tree -J                                                                                                 

/home/me/trash/tree-1.7.0
[{"type":"directory","name": ".","contents":[
    {"type":"file","name":"CHANGES"},
    {"type":"file","name":"color.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"color.o"},
    {"type":"directory","name":"doc","contents":[
      {"type":"file","name":"tree.1"},
      {"type":"file","name":"tree.1.fr"},
      {"type":"file","name":"xml.dtd"}
    ]},
    {"type":"file","name":"hash.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"hash.o"},
    {"type":"file","name":"html.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"html.o"},
    {"type":"file","name":"INSTALL"},
    {"type":"file","name":"json.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"json.o"},
    {"type":"file","name":"LICENSE"},
    {"type":"file","name":"Makefile"},
    {"type":"file","name":"README"},
    {"type":"file","name":"strverscmp.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"TODO"},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree"},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree.h"},
    {"type":"file","name":"tree.o"},
    {"type":"file","name":"unix.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"unix.o"},
    {"type":"file","name":"xml.c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"xml.o"}
  ]},
  {"type":"report","directories":1,"files":26}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using Perl and the JSON perl module.

```
$ tree | perl -e 'use JSON; @in=grep(s/\n$//, <>); \
     print encode_json(\@in)."\n";'
```

#### Example

Create some sample data.

```
$ mkdir -p dir{1..5}/dir{A,B}
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
$ tree 
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
|-- dir2
|   |-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
|-- dir3
|   |-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
|-- dir4
|   |-- dirA
|   `-- dirB
`-- dir5
    |-- dirA
    `-- dirB

15 directories, 0 files
```

Here's a run using the Perl command:

```
$ tree | perl -e 'use JSON; @in=grep(s/\n$//, <>); print encode_json(\@in)."\n";'
```

Which returns this output:

```
[".","|-- dir1","|   |-- dirA","|   `-- dirB","|-- dir2","|   |-- dirA","|   `-- dirB","|-- dir3","|   |-- dirA","|   `-- dirB","|-- dir4","|   |-- dirA","|   `-- dirB","`-- dir5","    |-- dirA","    `-- dirB","","15 directories, 0 files"]
```

**NOTE:** This is just an encapsulation of the output from `tree`. Not a nested hierarchy. The OP changed the question after I suggested this!

Answer (score 3):

I was also searching for a way to output a linux folder / file tree to some JSON or XML file. Why not use this simple terminal command:

```
    tree --dirsfirst --noreport -n -X -i -s -D -f -o my.xml
    
    --dirsfirst: list directories before files
    --noreport: don't print a report at the end of the listing
    -n: turn colors off
    -X: XML output
    -i: don't indent lines
    -s  print the size in bytes of each file
    -D: print the date of the last modification time
    -f: print the full path of each file
    -o my.xml: output file
```

So, just the Linux `tree` command, and config your own parameters. Here `-X` gives XML output.  For me, that's OK, and I guess there's some script to convert XML to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job. https://gist.github.com/debodirno/18a21df0511775c19de8d7ccbc99cb72

```
import os
import sys
import json

def tree_path_json(path):
    dir_structure = {}
    base_name = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(path))
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        dir_structure[base_name] = [ tree_path_json(os.path.join(path, file_name))\
         for file_name in os.listdir(path) ]
    else:
        return os.path.basename(path)
    return dir_structure

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    path = sys.argv[1]
else:
    path = '.'

print json.dumps(tree_path_json(path), indent = 4, separators = (', ', ' : '))
```

Comment: So this converts the tree structure to json. Run this code on a directory and it will produce the json as indicated in the question.