# The reverse of `tree` - reconstruct file and directory structure from text file contents?

Tags: files, text-processing, scripting, tree

We all know we can use `tree` to get a nicely formatted text "visualization" of the structure of a directory; say:

```
$ tree -spugD /usr/include/boost/accumulators/numeric/
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/numeric/
├── [drwxr-xr-x root     root            4096 Dec 19  2011]  detail
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root            2681 Oct 21  2010]  function1.hpp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root             406 Oct 21  2010]  function2.hpp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root             409 Oct 21  2010]  function3.hpp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root             409 Oct 21  2010]  function4.hpp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root            6725 Oct 21  2010]  function_n.hpp
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- root     root             530 Oct 21  2010]  pod_singleton.hpp
├── [drwxr-xr-x root     root            4096 Dec 19  2011]  functional
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root            2316 Oct 21  2010]  complex.hpp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root           16627 Oct 21  2010]  valarray.hpp
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- root     root           12219 Oct 21  2010]  vector.hpp
├── [-rw-r--r-- root     root            9473 Oct 21  2010]  functional_fwd.hpp
└── [-rw-r--r-- root     root           21312 Oct 21  2010]  functional.hpp

2 directories, 11 files
```

What I would want, is the reverse of this - given a text file with the contents as above save in `dirstruct.txt`, I could write something like this (pseudo):

```
$ reverse-tree dirstruct.txt -o /media/destpath
```

... and so, `/media/destpath` directory would be created if it doesn't exist, and inside I would get `detail` subfolder with files `function1.hpp`, etc; as per the tree above.

Of course, I can always do a copy `cp -a` and get the same; the idea here would be, that I could change filenames, directory names, sizes, permissions and timestamps in the textfile - and have *that* reconstructed in the output structure. For files, I first thought I'd be happy with them just being `touch`ed (that is, 0 bytes in size) - but it's probably better that the size is reconstructed too - by filling either 0x00 or random bytes, up to the requested size.

Primary use of this would be actually to post questions `:)` - some of those rely on a directory structure, say from a program I have installed; but the program in itself is irrelevant to the question; then instead of targetting answerers that may happen to have the program installed, I could simply ask a question in respect to an "anonymized" directory tree, which they themselves could quickly reconstruct on their machines, simply by pasting the tree text description in the post.

So - is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Probably not straightforward, but feasible if someone has the time

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier to parse the output of a suitable `find` command instead of using `tree`

Comment: Maybe some idea from [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90115/44370)...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool that I've ever seen. You could write a script in a variety of scripting languages, including Bash, to parse the output from `tree` and reconstruct a corresponding directory on disk that matched it. Looking through the text file would require a `while` or `for` loop and making use of `mkdir` or `mkdiir -p` to create a directory or a nested directory structure, followed by the use of the `touch` command to create empty versions of the files in the text file as well.

You could even replicate the timestamps associated since `mkdir` and `touch` both offer this as a argument as well if you wanted to get the structure fully replicated.

Comment: Thanks for that @sim - confirms at least there isn't such tool already existing; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As I needed this again, I put together a Perl script that does it; it turned out to be somewhat complicated, so I released it here:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/single-scripts/revrs-tree.pl

What it does, is that it parses the output from `tree` - but unlike the OP example, it also needs the `--dirsfirst` option. To avoid remembering all that, the `revrs-tree.pl` can be used first like this:

```bash
perl revrs-tree.pl --getdir /usr/include/boost/accumulators/ > test.tree
```

... which will simply call `tree` with the right options, which outputs to stdout - we capture that in a file `test.tree`.

Then, we call the same script on the this `test.tree` content; but the trick is that, the output is not the directories/files themselves - but lines in a `bash` script instead, printed to stdout. The call looks like this:

```bash
perl revrs-tree.pl --zerofill test.tree > test-tree.sh
# alternatively, can receive tree text from stdin:
cat test.tree | perl revrs-tree.pl --zerofill > test-tree.sh
```

... and `test-tree.sh` then contains stuff like:

```bash
RTD="/usr/include/boost/accumulators";
read -p "WARNING! will output in '$RTD' directory!
Press [Enter] key to start output...";
if [ ! -d "$RTD" ] ; then mkdir "$RTD" ; fi ;

TDIR="$RTD/framework";
mkdir "$TDIR"; sudo chown root:root "$TDIR"; sudo chmod 755 "$TDIR"; sudo touch -d 'Jul 16 2014 9:43:00' "$TDIR";

TDIR="$RTD/framework/accumulators";
mkdir "$TDIR"; sudo chown root:root "$TDIR"; sudo chmod 755 "$TDIR"; sudo touch -d 'Jul 16 2014 9:43:00' "$TDIR";

TFIL="$RTD/framework/accumulators/droppable_accumulator.hpp";
cat /dev/zero | head --bytes 9740 >  "$TFIL";
touch -d 'Oct 21 2010 0:00:00' "$TFIL"; sudo chown root:root "$TFIL"; sudo chmod 644 "$TFIL";
...
```

The trick here is:

- Remember to change the `RTD` before you run the script - I didn't once, and managed to overwrite `/usr/include/boost/accumulators` with zero-filled files! (which then required `sudo apt-get remove --purge libboost1.42-dev && sudo apt-get install libboost1.42-dev` for me) !!! (that is why the script will wait at start for user input) ... Let's say here you've changed it to `/tmp/newtarget`.
- `tree` does not give full timestamps - so times are usually set to 0
- `tree` also truncates uids/gids to some 7 or 8 characters - so if you have longer than those, inspect the `.sh` script, and replace where appropriate.

Then, because it happened the OP example was `root` owned directory, the `.sh` script contains `sudo` at appropriate places, so you might as well call it as super user:

```
sudo bash test-tree.sh
```

After a lot of `set -x` printouts, the script should complete; then you can check whether the directory/file tree structure is reconstructed correctly with, say, `diff` - or `meld`:

```
meld <(tree -spugD /tmp/newtarget/) <(tree -spugD /usr/include/boost/accumulators/)
```

This gives me no difference in `tree` output (for this example), apart from the root directory.